# Is it bad practice to create a thread in a shared library?

Tags: c++, multithreading, shared-libraries

I am creating a shared library, with a class that creates a thread in its constructor which runs it until the destructor is called. All methods of this class are thread-safe. Something like this:

```
class NetworkRPCConnection {
  std::thread t;
public:
  NetworkRPCConnection() : t([](){maintain_connection();}) {}
  ~NetworkRPCConnection(){close_connection(); t.join();}
}
```

This works fine, but is it bad practice to create a thread in a shared library? Is it worth mentioning in the API documentation, or is it better to hide this implementation detail?

Comment: Definitely document it in the API.

Comment: Well, all the books I read say, that implementation details should be hidden out of documentation. Why the developer would want to know, if the library uses threads?

Comment: The developer needs to know because they might use threads and if something else is using them then that's more strain on that resource.  Also, threads often require special build configurations and options to be incorperated into the build system.

Comment: @GamePad64 All your books are wrong. Ok, they are partially wrong. You should use your judgement when hiding implementation details, not just hide them all at random. I sure as hell would be interested to know that your module requires 20 GBytes of ram, for example. In this case, I would be interested from a threading resource perspective.

Comment: If a library uses threads I might need to be careful about changing the global locale, or installing signal handlers, or calling non-reentrant functions such as `gmtime` that write to static data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general it's best to avoid creating threads in shared libraries, but there are circumstances where it is OK - but in these cases, you really do need to document it in your API.

The reason you need to document it is that threads can interact in hard to predict ways with certain operations - notably `fork()` and signals; this makes it impossible to completely "hide" the thread as an implementation detail, because the library user needs to be aware of it.

As for why it's better not to create threads: usually the user of the library has a better idea of their threading model - for instance, they may already have a thread that the work could be done in, so creating another one only creates extra overhead (and constrains their implementation). But if you know the requirements of the library's user very well, and know that an exclusive thread is needed, and can take care of all aspects of the thread's lifetime - then it may be OK to create and manage the thread yourself - but, as mentioned above, you definitely do need to document it.